# How do I interpret a negative relative standard deviation and a relative standard deviation greater than 100 in this example?

Tags: standard-deviation, percentage

I have the following astronomical data
data1vcoord =array([[ 709.4497, 1500.3387, 1573.9434,  292.9126,  930.4643],
[1423.7768, 1242.1892,  407.6168,  346.3528,  541.8568]])

data10vcoord=array([[ 718.5531, 1505.431 , 1579.0752,  298.2245,  935.6432],
[1379.5269, 1236.0935,  401.8907,  341.7608,  535.6279]])

which are coordinates of stars in 2 images, and I want to calulate the standard deviation of the shifts and say how good or bad it is. The following are python commands

```
shift=data1vcoord-data10vcoord
shiftx,shifty=shift

meanshiftx=shiftx.mean()
meanshifty=shifty.mean()
meanshiftx
-5.963659999999971
meanshifty
13.378520000000037

stdshiftsx = np.std(shiftx)
stdshiftsy = np.std(shifty)
relstdshiftsx= 100*stdshiftsx/meanshiftx
relstdshiftsy= 100*stdshiftsy/meanshifty

#How wel do the values agree? To answer the question let's find the relative standard deviation 
​
stdshiftsx = np.std(shiftx)
stdshiftsy = np.std(shifty)


relstdshiftsx= 100*stdshiftsx/meanshiftx
relstdshiftsy= 100*stdshiftsy/meanshifty
stdshiftsx
1.571614833984457
stdshiftsy
15.446430668397145

Here I am computing the relative standarddeviation
relstdshiftsx
-26.35319307244988
relstdshiftsy
relstdshiftsy
115.45694642155561
```

question: How do I interpret these results?

**1) relstdshiftsx= -26.35319307244988
The formula for the relative standar deviation that I used is 100*SD/mean, if the mean is negative as it happened in my case for one of my means, this value is negative, so how do I interpret this?**

**2)relstdshiftsy= 115.45694642155561
How come I am getting more than 115, it is supposed to be a percentage, doesn't it? I should be getting at most 100**

Comment: Relative coordinates rarely are meaningful because they can totally change simply by changing the origin of the coordinate system.  And percents can be literally any number (even negative), because they are merely re-expressing ratios.  What, then, you you intend to mean by "interpret"?

Comment: @whuber This are shift in coordinates, but that does not matter, forget they are coordinates. what is the range of acceptable values for a relative std deviation to consider it low? 0 to x%, x=?

Comment: and 115%? Shouldn't the relative std be less than 100, since it in percentange?

Comment: That's unanswerable because (1) as I said, your statistics are meaningless and (2) even if they were meaningful, that's a question for your application, whatever it might be.  I recommend you review the concept of percent (with a focus on the distinction between percent and proportion) before proceeding.

Comment: @whuber Why is the statistics not meaningful? These are not relative coordinates. The data are the variation of coordinates (shifts) in two pictures that a camera is taking. The image is not supposed to move, but due to imperfections in the camera or many other reasons, the image may move a bit. So we have these shifts and want to assess how good or bad is this variability. So we are not supposed to change the origin or anything, although that may not affect the shift between two images either

Comment: And I haven't invented this stuff, it is standard in astronomy. And my question was about the relative standard deviation. I wanted a normalized interpretation of the standard deviation so I found this concept of relative standard deviation but it looks like it is not a number between 0 and 100 in absolute value, unless numpy is calculating the standard deviation with "n-1" in the denominator, and I getting another value of standard deviation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the shift data you seem to be analysing:

```
> shift
      shiftx  shifty
[1,] -9.1034 44.2499
[2,] -5.0923  6.0957
[3,] -5.1318  5.7261
[4,] -5.3119  4.5920
[5,] -5.1789  6.2289
```

So $x$s shifted down and $y$s up (and the first pair of shifts looks distinct compared to the other four).

- Since all the $x$ shifts were negative, $\bar x$ was also negative while $s_x$ is inevitably positive, and so $\frac{s_x}{\bar x}$ is also negative and you calculate it as $-26\%$ (without Bessel's correction).  Shifts can be in either direction so the sign should not worry you.
- Since one of the $y$ shifts is over $7$ times the others, $s_y$ is large compared to $\bar y$, and you calculate $\frac{s_y}{\bar y}$ as $115\%$.  This highlights the consequence of a massive outlier in the shift data.

Percentages are frequently understood as a positive fraction of a positive whole.  But your calculations just divide one number by another, where the numerator is not part of the denominator and where the numerator and denominator can have different signs.  So the naive expectation that percentages should be between $0\%$ and $100\%$ does not apply here, since your calculations do not follow the naive assumptions about percentages.